# What would be the best way to make this run Async

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, httpurlconnection

I have to java classes, one the activity and the other is the class i want to run a void from.
Web.java looks like:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Web {
    public Document requestPage(String urll) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        URL url = new URL(urll);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
        rd.close();
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(result.toString());
        return doc;
    }
}
```

And my MainActivity.java looks like this:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button Visit;
    EditText Urlbox;
    Web web = new Web();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Visit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button);
        Urlbox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText);
        Visit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Document lol = web.requestPage(Urlbox.getText().toString());
                if(lol.text().toString() != null){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Visit success!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this works fine over the main thread most, but i want to make it go over a different thread so my UI doesnt get jammed if the connection is bad
How would i make this work in async? This is my first time i use async but i just dont understand how i should use it, ive spent a few days trying to figure it out with absolutely no success
So if i could get some examples that do work that would be fantastic so i could compare it to my current code and learn what i did wrong

Comment: You didn't try to make an AsyncTask first? If so, please [edit] and show your attempt. If you want an easier way to make a network request, then use Volley or OkHttp

Comment: You van check my answer it will really helpful fir you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289109/calling-a-async-task-and-waiting-for-answer/37292163?noredirect=1#comment62112709_37292163

Answer (score 0):

i handle sitution like with [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) Pattern its the best option for `Asynchronous networking` or you can use `AsyncTask` but im explain `cllback` pattern so lets make it happen

first create `callback` interface

```
public interface Request {

    void onSuccess(Document doc);

}
```

2 - implements `Runnable` for running `Asynchronous` request on another thread

```
public class Web implements Runnable {

   public final Request request;
   private final String urll;       

    Web(String urll,  Request request){
       this.urll = urll;
       this.request = request;
    }


    @Override public void run() {
       try{
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        URL url = new URL(urll);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
        rd.close();
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(result.toString());
        // fill the cllback with result
        this.request.onSuccess(doc);
         }
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }

//            return doc;
  }
}
```

3 - now we work with `ExecutorService`(`ThreadPools` created for reason .. its off topic here), simple thing in here we use `new Thread(Runnable)` before that lets`implement` the `calback`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implement Request{

    Button Visit;
    EditText Urlbox;
    private Document lol;
  //Web web = new Web();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Visit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button);
        Urlbox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText);
        Visit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Document lol = web.requestPage(Urlbox.getText().toString());
                String url = Urlbox.getText().toString();
                Thread thread = new Thread(new Web(url, this));
                 thread.start();
                if(lol.text().toString() != null){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Visit success!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                 thread.interrupt();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Document doc) {
       lol = doc;
    }
}
```

**and every where you need `new` result or request you have to create thread and if you wanna share result betwwen classes or thread this is another thing**

this pattern works perfectly me.

Comment: You can also use callbacks in an AsyncTask. Using the thread pool seems like more work than required

Comment: @cricket_007 `AsyncTask` have lot ‍‍‍ ‍‍‍‍`issues` ‍‍ with `parallelism` and  `finish` the job and `manage` the request

Comment: But the question only asked how to make the shown code asynchronous and it's only a web request, so while your answer may provide a solution, it's more complex than necessary. That's all

Comment: `What would be the best way to make this run Async`

Comment: And 'best' is an opinion, so you have your way, which may work, and I have mine (use a library like Volley or OkHttp)

Comment: Unrelated question, but how would one do this when instead of calling the request in an activity class one calls in another class?
So for example you have MainActivity.java, process.java, reques.java(interface) and Web.java (runable)
What how would you execute the thread in process.java instead of executing it in MainActivity.java? @Hosseini

Comment: when you `fill callback with data` in your case `Document Object` its will be available every where (every where you can access to request for example `process java - Implement Request` ) i try edit my _answer_