# Can't post param value

Tags: android, post, urlconnection

Following code helps to post data to server. It was working very well but now I have to send a string named as **token**.

I also used different ways like to send params but still I get error code

> 400: bad request

All I get is that token value somehow causes some problems. If you try code it will send message like result will be:

`{"durum":"hata","mesaj":"token_gerekli"}` it is supposed to be something like `{"durum":"hata","mesaj":"token_zaman_Aşımı"}`

```
 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        try
        {
            String link = "http://cvbenim.com/api/v1/isveren/uyeliktamamla";
            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoInput(true);

            String token="eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjQsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL3Byb2plLmFwcFwvYXBpXC92MVwvZ2lyaXMiLCJpYXQiOjE0NTk5NTA5NTQsImV4cCI6MTQ1OTk3NjE1NCwibmJmIjoxNDU5OTUwOTU0LCJqdGkiOiIwMzRhYmEyY2JmYWEyODg4ZmZjY2ZiZjAxZDA3OTI1YyJ9.Saan9lSUb3FWeFfSNWO4hKyFU-osca0T32CdjC-9Kd8";
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("token",token)
                    .appendQueryParameter("firma_adi","SomeName")
                    .appendQueryParameter("sektor", "1")
                    .appendQueryParameter("sehir", "2")
                    .appendQueryParameter("ilce", "3")
                    .appendQueryParameter("semt","4")
                    .appendQueryParameter("adres","SomePlace")
                    .appendQueryParameter("telefon","02122342111")
                    .appendQueryParameter("email", "someName@gmail.com")
                    .appendQueryParameter("web","dogu.com");


            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();

            connection.connect();
            InputStream is ;
            if(connection.getResponseCode()>=400)
                is=connection.getErrorStream();
            else
                is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            String line = "0";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            is.close();
            String result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("Final Result ",result);

            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.obj = result;
            mh.sendMessage(msg);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: you can use this check my answer it handles GET and POST with cookies http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289109/calling-a-async-task-and-waiting-for-answer?noredirect=1#comment62106624_37289109

Comment: I check that answer but hard to apply, Which part of my code should I modify I couldnt understand

Comment: all the data that you are posting is receving at api except token. is it?

Comment: Yes, You are right

Comment: the work you are doing in do in background just call my method ` Connection.postAPIResponse(address, strJsonData);` where address is your url and strJsonData is formed to post data. calll  it in back ground and check response

Comment: you need to take your web api for test. which data is mapping or not to you api.

Comment: I tested web api it works correctly

Comment: i am getting response {"durum":"hata","mesaj":"token_gerekli"} with my method

Comment: can you post your web api. which is it

Comment: I am working on the answer you suggested I will send you it but can you open chat

Comment: you don't have enough reputation till now. to chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the following response:

```
{"durum":"hata","mesaj":"token_gerekli"}
```

With the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://cvbenim.com/api/v1/isveren/uyeliktamamla" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjQsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL3Byb2plLmFwcFwvYXBpXC92MVwvZ2lyaXMiLCJpYXQiOjE0NTk5NTA5NTQsImV4cCI6MTQ1OTk3NjE1NCwibmJmIjoxNDU5OTUwOTU0LCJqdGkiOiIwMzRhYmEyY2JmYWEyODg4ZmZjY2ZiZjAxZDA3OTI1YyJ9.Saan9lSUb3FWeFfSNWO4hKyFU-osca0T32CdjC-9Kd8"
<input type="hidden" name="firma_adi" value="SomeName" />
<input type="hidden" name="sektor" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="sehir" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="ilce" value="3" />
<input type="hidden" name="semt" value="4" />
<input type="hidden" name="adres" value="SomePlace" />
<input type="hidden" name="telefon" value="02122342111" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="someName@gmail.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="web" value="dogu.com" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So this points to something wrong with your reading of the API or the connection or something else. That is, you are getting the correct response from the `cvbenim.com` API based on what you are passing it (well, posting to it really).

Comment: thanks for the answer, I use chrome's post man to test api. But problem is that I cant find trouble in my code

Comment: Are you saying you get a valid (correct) response when posting using the Chrome extension "Postman", but invalid when posting from your App?

Comment: that is right, I use same token on Postman it works but doesnt work wiith my code

Comment: OK, and I also got the error, so this points to some issue / feature with the API that is different when called from your desktop and when called from somewhere else (for example, your App, my desktop). Is it IP restricted? Does the API require a certain User-Agent? These are the sort of questions you need to ask now.

Comment: so now I have to work on this answer I hope İt will help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289109)

Answer (score 1):

I found solution it was some server problem I sent token with **GET** and other params with usual **Post** it works. In case somebody need it here is my solution.

```js
           String link = "http://cvbenim.com/api/v1/isveren/uyeliktamamla?token="+token;

           URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoInput(true);

            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("firma_adi","SomeName")
                    .appendQueryParameter("sektor", "1")
                    .appendQueryParameter("sehir", "2")
                    .appendQueryParameter("ilce", "3")
                    .appendQueryParameter("semt","4")
                    .appendQueryParameter("adres","SomePlace")
                    .appendQueryParameter("telefon","02122342111")
                    .appendQueryParameter("email", "someName@gmail.com")
                    .appendQueryParameter("web","dogu.com");


            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();

            connection.connect();
```