# How to use POST method inside HttpUrlConnection

Tags: android

I am trying to use HttpUrlConnection class in Async Task inside doInBackground method.

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String strUrl=String.format("%s",SERVER_URL);
        try {

            URL url =new URL(strUrl);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");

            String str="{\"userid\":\"1\"}";
            byte[] outputInBytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
            OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            os.write( outputInBytes );
os.close();


            InputStream stream1=urlConnection.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream1);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int chr;
        while((chr=reader.read())!=-1)
        {
            builder.append((char)chr);
        }
        String result=builder.toString();

 return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 return null;
    }
```

But I am getting null instead of result,what will be the problem here.

Comment: debug your code and check once your code flow

Comment: you can use this for both get and post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289109/calling-a-async-task-and-waiting-for-answer?noredirect=1#comment62106624_37289109

Comment: you are getting null on server code or in result?, value of result will be anything that server responds with.

Comment: @AbhishekK i am getting null in result

Comment: after debugging i came to know that i am getting null in result String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally my code works well, it needs some changes like:-

By this method our URL get chunked into certain packets.

```
urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);//No use in my code
```

As i am using hard coded string of JSON, which is treated as a simple String.So instead of "application/json", i've to use "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as given below.

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");//incorrect
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");//when we need to pass string inside POST body.
```

It is for connecting to POST method URL.

```
urlConnection.connect();
```

If i am having wrong concept somewhere ,Please let me know about it.